# Term for when all players go all-in and show hands

Tags: all-in, terminology

Is there a term for when all players—or all but one player—have gone all in, and all hole cards are revealed before the remaining cards are dealt?

I don't mean all players at the table are all-in. I just mean when all players remaining in the pot are all-in. The term I was looking for is for when the hole cards are revealed before the flop/turn/river is dealt because no further betting can take place.

Comment: Maybe family showdown? It's made up but would suit this situation.

Comment: The only term that comes to my mind is: unlikely ;)

Comment: @mah I dont mean all players on the table are all in. I just mean all players remaining in the pot e.g. if there are three players still in and two/three of them are all-in

Answer (score 3):

The only one I've heard is something like "x-way all-in", for example "There's 4-way all-in".

Answer (score 0):

The term for the end of a hand is usually called a "Showdown".

Answer (score 0):

There is no special term for when the showdown is done before the river, it is still called "Showdown".

Answer (score 0):

I've heard dealers announce the situation you describe by saying "no more betting," "action is closed" and "the pot is closed." I suppose you could call it "action closed"?

Not the most intuitive name, but it is both specific and accurate, unlike, say, "showdown," which does technically apply but is not specific to your situation.